# Can't connect to my home ehternet network with 18.04 - Cable unplugged

Tags: 18.04, ethernet

I can't connect to my home ethernet network on my laptop as Ubuntu 18.04 says "cable unplugged" although it's definitely plugged in. I have no such issue with Windows 7 on the same laptop.

I've tried the following fixes to the same issue, but none worked.

- removing the battery and waiting 15 minutes before restarting the laptop ;
- installing ifplugd (a daemon that's supposed to check the statut of the cable) and restarting the laptop.

**ifconfig**

```
enp7s0f5: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
ether f4:6d:04:51:d1:6a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
device interrupt 35
```

**dmesg | grep eth**

```
[    1.339232] jme: JMicron JMC2XX ethernet driver version 1.0.8
[    1.340310] jme 0000:07:00.5 eth0: JMC250 Gigabit Ethernet chiprev:23 pcirev:3 macaddr:f4:6d:04:51:d1:6a
[    1.352643] jme 0000:07:00.5 enp7s0f5: renamed from eth0
```

**lsmod**

```
ccm                    20480  6
uvcvideo               94208  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       53248  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              217088  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
mc                     53248  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek   126976  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
coretemp               20480  0
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
kvm_intel             253952  0
snd_hda_intel          49152  6
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  1 snd_hda_intel
kvm                   655360  1 kvm_intel
snd_hda_codec         131072  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           90112  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
ath9k                 151552  0
i915                 1978368  35
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              475136  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
drm_kms_helper        184320  1 i915
snd_pcm               102400  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
intel_cstate           20480  0
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
ath                    36864  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
drm                   491520  19 drm_kms_helper,i915
mac80211              851968  1 ath9k
mei_me                 40960  0
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
cfg80211              712704  4 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath,mac80211
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
joydev                 28672  0
input_leds             16384  0
snd                    86016  23 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
mei                   102400  1 mei_me
serio_raw              20480  0
intel_ips              28672  0
asus_laptop            32768  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_laptop
input_polldev          20480  1 asus_laptop
lpc_ich                24576  0
mac_hid                16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
parport_pc             40960  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                53248  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
ahci                   40960  2
jme                    36864  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
psmouse               151552  0
sdhci_pci              53248  0
mii                    16384  1 jme
cqhci                  28672  1 sdhci_pci
sdhci                  65536  1 sdhci_pci
video                  49152  2 i915,asus_laptop
```

(Edit 1 - 17/09/2020)
I'm running desktop version.

**sudo lshw -C network**

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 01
       serial: 74:2f:68:1b:5d:7a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=5.4.0-47-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.39 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:f5400000-f540ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: JMC250 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: JMicron Technology Corp.
       physical id: 0.5
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.5
       logical name: enp7s0f5
       version: 03
       serial: f4:6d:04:51:d1:6a
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msix msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=jme driverversion=1.0.8 duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:35 memory:f0400000-f0403fff ioport:8100(size=128) ioport:8000(size=256)
```

**cat /etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

**cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml**

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Is this a Desktop or Server installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution :)

I installed ethtool

```
sudo apt-get install ethtool
```

and simply ran a command

```
sudo ethtool -s enp7s0f5 autoneg off speed 100 duplex full
```

where enp7s0f5 is my ehternet interface, obtained earlier with ifconfig.

That being said, I come to understand that this change will be discarded when I'll restart my PC, so I'll try and to have this command ran automatically at startup if that's the case. I'll edit this answer once I'm sure it's necessary and I know how to do that.