# Ubuntu 22.04 - Network - Wired Connection says Cable Unplugged

Tags: networking, 22.04, wired

I have a dual boot system running Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I cannot seem to get the wired connection to work correctly. I tried the following:

I installed ethtool

```
sudo apt-get install ethtool
```

and simply ran a command

```
sudo ethtool -s ens5f5 autoneg off speed 100 duplex full
```

where ens5f5 is my ehternet interface, obtained earlier with ifconfig.

I found that in [Can't connect to my home ehternet network with 18.04 - Cable unplugged](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1275428/cant-connect-to-my-home-ehternet-network-with-18-04-cable-unplugged) but when I implement that solution and run a speed test, it is much slower than using the wifi connection. I tried to substitute 1000 for the speed but it returns the error:
netlink error: Invalid argument

I am content with the wifi speed but am curious as to why the ethernet connection does not seem to want to work at an acceptable speed.

Comment: I forgot to mention that when I boot into Windows 10, the speedtest shows what I would expect from a wired connection so the issue does not seem to be related to the cable or the router.

Comment: Hey! Please consider formatting code in your question as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved

After re-installing Ubuntu 22.04 and then running:

```
sudo ethtool -s ens5f5 autoneg on speed 100 duplex full
```

I was able to achieve an acceptable speed from a speed test (a download speed of 93.45). I changed autoneg from off to on so I am not sure if that helped or if it was the fresh install of Ubuntu or a combination of the two, but I'll take it.

I then created a script to run on startup so I wouldn't have to run the command every time the computer booted up.

First, create a Systemd service file as in an example below (the file I created was /etc/systemd/system/start-ethernet.service):

```
[Unit]
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/start-ethernet.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

After: Instructs systemd on when the script should be run. In our case the script will run after network connection. Other example could be mysql.target etc.

ExecStart: This field provides a full path to the actual script to be executed on startup

WantedBy: Into what boot target the systemd unit should be installed

Create a script to be executed on Ubuntu system startup. As specified in the above Step 1, the path and the name of the new script is /usr/local/bin/start-ethernet.sh.

The below is an example of such script:

```
#!/bin/bash

ethtool -s ens5f5 autoneg on speed 100 duplex full
```

Set appropriate permissions for both, the Systemd service unit and script:

```
$ sudo chmod 744 /usr/local/bin/start-ethernet.sh

$ sudo chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/start-ethernet.service
```

Next enable the service unit:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload

$ sudo systemctl enable start-ethernet.service
```

Now you are ready to reboot your system. Once it reboots, the wired connection should be active.

I found the instructions for creating and running the startup script in: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-run-script-on-startup-on-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish-server-desktop and then I tailored them for my own use.